# IBM Watson Conversation: Keep relative scoring after workspace upgrade?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using conversation version 2016-09-20 and I'm happy with the dialog results. Now I want to upgrade to version 2017-04-21 for some new features. In that process I need to upgrade the conversation workspace.

Is it possible for me to turn off absolute scoring but keep relative scoring?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is not possible to keep "old behavior" after upgrading a workspace. In your case, the scoring would change from relative to absolute scoring. This will impact how and which intents are going to be returned.

There are some [general guidelines on upgrading workspaces](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/upgrading.html). The [changes to the scoring and the impact on a workspace](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/intents-entities.html#absolute-scoring-and-mark-as-irrelevant) are discussed in the feature overview. It will require changes to your dialog and hence some testing.